# How to create a java.io.File instance diectly from content without creating a temporary file on disk ?

Tags: java, java-io

I have a library that sends an attachment along with an email after accepting a java.io.File instance as attachment. 
Now I have html content with me to send as an attachment.

Is it possible to create a File instance to pass to this Java API when I have the content instead of creating a temporary physical file on disk ?

Comment: No. (filler text to make it 15 characters long)

Answer (score 2):

A File is just a filename. There is nothing on the disk when you instantiate one unless there really is such a file, or you do some I/O, or you call `createNewFile()` and friends.